# How to do language translation in MFE using angular? When I switch language in shell project, how can we translate in remote projects too?

Tags: angular, shell, internationalization, translation, micro-frontend

Am using angular i18n @angular/localize library.

Trying to do multi- language translation in Micro frontend architecture project. If am switching language in shell, how we supposed to share the translation language to remote since translation can happen only during build time.

Any possibility to maintain the common translation file in shell?.